# How to Open Google Street View App from an another iOS App

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, google-street-view

To open the google maps iOS app using the following link as the reference https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/urlscheme.

I have a requirement to check and open the google street view iOS app. Please help me if anyone know the url scheme for it and how to check the google map in my device and open it using URL scheme.

Comment: Any luck with the below answer?

Comment: @valosip not yet checked. Will check them and update you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated answer to reflect google street views app instead of google maps street view option**

```
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:
     [NSURL URLWithString:@"streetview://"]]) {
  NSLog(@"Google Street View is installed");
} else {
  NSLog(@"Google Street View is not installed");
}
```

Comment: yes it works for me. Do you know how to open a particular place street view using it?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't.   I'll be able to take a look tomorrow.     Take a look at the street view api or the google maps for ideas:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/streetview/      .....    
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/streetview

Comment: Did you have any luck on opening a specific place?  If my answer to your original question worked, please accept it!

Comment: Thanks, It has helped to open street view iOS app. In the mean time google has fixed the issue of open street view in google maps iOS app.

Comment: If you use a highlighted panorama it works. Try this link: http://www.google.com/maps/streetview/#us-highlights/faneuil-hall-boston . But just for a featured location.